# Most efficent way to show a small animation above a button in ios?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, animation

Which i would like to embed within my iphone app above a field which includes a button which the user would press to sign up. Thanks in advance!!
The rest of this text is to help increase the quality standard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this kind of animation by using UIView animation:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
     button.frame = CGRectMake(20, 10, 50, 10); // the final button frame
}];
```

Comment: It should be noted that if the button is using auto-layout, you would animate the constraints on the button instead of the buttons frame.